# Is there any prize for proving conjecture on Fermat's prime ?-+

Tags: reference-request, prime-numbers

I know this site is for mathematical questions and answer places, but I need a little help from you in some other aspect. I have searched in google but didn't get any satisfactory answer for it. This is why I am requesting you to help me or atleast provide me some information or link from which I can get my answer. Also I apologize as I could not figure out what should be title and tags for this query so I gave some thing.

The query is: "fermat's primes are finite" ---is it still a conjecture? What are the researches have been made so far? In arxive I didn't get any such special thng. One more thing, is there any special prize money declared on this conjecture? If so, how can I know that?

Please provide me some details or any links where I can get the answers. I know it is not any mathematical problem to ask for help but I have tried to get the answer but in vain. Please help me.

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: As far as I know the question is still open. I do not know of any prize offered for its solution.

Comment: @AlexBecker Sir, Is there any website or any person who can give me answer for it?

Comment: Not that I know of. This one is as good as any I suppose.

Comment: There is a prize: I will give you $20 for the solution.

Comment: Yes there is, it's called the the prize of satisfaction.

Comment: But there is a negative prize associated to the fact that one does not move even one's little finger to acknowledge that some answer to one's question has been posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several [individual mathematicians](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/66084/open-problems-with-monetary-rewards) have proposed as rewards and/or incentives for the solution of various conjectures moderate or insignificant sums of money, and even rather exotic objects. The late Paul Erdős was (also) famous for the former, and Stanislaw Mazur awarding Per Enflo a live goose (see the details on the link) is an example of the latter.

In a rather different perspective, Andrew Beal (a banker) offers a hefty sum for the proof of [a conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beal%27s_conjecture) named either after him or Tijdeman-Zagier conjecture.

Apart these and the infamous [Millenium prize problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millennium_Prize_Problems) (associated to vastly higher sums of money), the lists of such prizes that I know do not include the result you are interested in, hence the answer to your question is most probably: No.

Comment: I think it's fair to say that it's a folklore conjecture that 65537 is the largest Fermat prime. I would ask Sam Wagstaff if he knows of a reward. The goose story was Stanislaw Mazur. Barry Mazur has offered a $5 reward for an impossibly weak proof of Dirichlet's theorem on primes in arithmetic progression. The point of the offer was to illustrate the importance of aggregates in arithmetic. http://www.math.harvard.edu/~mazur/papers/Erdos.lecture.6.pdf

Comment: @JamieWeigandt Thanks for the complements. Mazur blunder corrected.